# How to connect the Power BI Cloud to PostgreSql DB(on Azure)

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-datasource

I have my ERP database - PostgreSql on my Azure VM. I want to connect the Power BI Cloud to pull the dash board and reports. Is that possible right now?
[image]

I have checked the Cloud Power BI and could not found any solution to PostgreSql.

Is there any alternative solutions to achieve the Live Dashboards of my ERP(DB- on Azure-Postgres)?